# Generate the CER file from the batch file. how to attach file to a bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Can I combine two files (a batch file and a `cer` file) in a single file which is 
an executable.

I have a certificate which is `.cer` to install and some tasks like service start/stop ping in a batch file.

Now, I want to make a single file which is extract a `cer` file and execute batch file.

***Edit*:**
The first file task and other is .cer file. First file has set password for local user, start /stop some services, system information, scan with trend micro to specific folder, etc, and other is a certificate (.cer). When I run bat file I need to put this (.cer) file here where bat file located. I want to a trick though make a single file. When I run it the task completed with install this certificate too.

Comment: What's in the two files? Which type of program do you want to combine these files?

Comment: The first file task and other is .cer file. First file has set password for local user, start /stop some services, system information, scan with trend micro to specific folder, etc, and other is a certificate (.cer). When I run bat file I need to put this (.cer) file here where bat file located. I want to a trick though make a single file. When I run it the task completed with install this certificate too.

Comment: Thank very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it is possible but need these steps...

**1)** Make an encode base64 from file cer:

```bat
 %__appdir__%certutil -encode /f file.cer cert_b64.txt
```

**2)** Move all lines in `cert_b64.txt` to bat

```bat
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
 Q2VydGlmaWNhdGU6CiAgICBEYXRhOgogICAgICAgIFZlcnNpb246IDMgKDB4MikK 
 .....in all lines .....
 ajBGc2x4Y1ZLZFZqNWdsVmNTbWtMd1pLYkVVMU9Ld2xlVC9pWEZodm9vV2hRPT0K 
 LS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQo= 
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**3)** Decode `string in base64` in your bat `(%~f0)` to `file.cer`, to be able to use it:

```bat
  %__appdir__%certutil -decode -f "%~f0" "%tmp%\cert.cer"
```

**4)** Use `file.crt` in the task you need!

See an example use below of `alice.crt` file sample from [here](https://github.com/freelan-developers/freelan/wiki/Sample-certificate-files):

```bat
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0" & setlocal & title <nul & title ...\%~0

%__appdir__%certutil.exe -decode /f "%~f0" ".\cert.cer" 2>&1 >nul
if not exist ".\cert.cer" set/p "=Decoding Error File!" && exit/b 

:: here your code come to do more tasks, so, do anything you need
:: the last bat line needs to be like below for delete .\cert.cer

del /q /f ".\cert.cer" 2>&1 >nul & endlocal & exit/b || goto :eof

rem :: your base64 attached file below, for mutiple file use .zip 

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Q2VydGlmaWNhdGU6CiAgICBEYXRhOgogICAgICAgIFZlcnNpb246IDMgKDB4MikKICAgICAgICBTZXJpYWwgTnVtYmVyOiAxICgweDEpCiAgICAgICAgU2lnbmF0dXJl
IEFsZ29yaXRobTogc2hhMVdpdGhSU0FFbmNyeXB0aW9uCiAgICAgICAgSXNzdWVyOiBDPUZSLCBTVD1BbHNhY2UsIEw9U3RyYXNib3VyZywgTz13d3cuZnJlZWxhbi5v
cmcsIE9VPWZyZWVsYW4sIENOPUZyZWVsYW4gU2FtcGxlIENlcnRpZmljYXRlIEF1dGhvcml0eS9lbWFpbEFkZHJlc3M9Y29udGFjdEBmcmVlbGFuLm9yZwogICAgICAg
IFZhbGlkaXR5CiAgICAgICAgICAgIE5vdCBCZWZvcmU6IEFwciAyNyAxMDozMToxOCAyMDEyIEdNVAogICAgICAgICAgICBOb3QgQWZ0ZXIgOiBBcHIgMjUgMTA6MzE6
MTggMjAyMiBHTVQKICAgICAgICBTdWJqZWN0OiBDPUZSLCBTVD1BbHNhY2UsIE89d3d3LmZyZWVsYW4ub3JnLCBPVT1mcmVlbGFuLCBDTj1hbGljZS9lbWFpbEFkZHJl
c3M9Y29udGFjdEBmcmVlbGFuLm9yZwogICAgICAgIFN1YmplY3QgUHVibGljIEtleSBJbmZvOgogICAgICAgICAgICBQdWJsaWMgS2V5IEFsZ29yaXRobTogcnNhRW5j
cnlwdGlvbgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgUHVibGljLUtleTogKDQwOTYgYml0KQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgTW9kdWx1czoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAwMDpk
ZDo2ZDpiZDpmODo4MDpmYTpkNzpkZToxYjoxZjphNzphMzoyZTpiMjoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAwMjplMjoxNjpmNjo1MjowYTozYzpiZjphNjo0MjpmODpj
YTpkYzo5Mzo2NzoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA0ZDo2MDpjMzo0Zjo4ZDpjMzo4YTowMDoxYjpmMTpjNDo0Yjo0MTo2YTo2OToKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
ICBkMjo2OTplNTozZjoyMTo4ZTpjNTowYjpmODoyMjozNzphZDpiNjoyYzo0YjoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA1NTpmZjo3YTowMzo3MjpiYjo5YTpkMzplYzo5
NjpiOTo1Njo5ZjpjYjoxOToKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA5OTpjOTozMjo5NDo2Zjo4ZjpjNjo1MjowNjo5Zjo0NTowMzpkZjpmZDplODoKICAgICAgICAgICAg
ICAgICAgICA5NzpmNjplYTpkNjpiYTpiYjo0ODoyYjpiNTplMDozNDo2MTo0ZDo1MjozNjoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAwZjphYjo4Nzo1MjoyNTowMzpjZjo4
NzowMDo4NzoxMzpmMjpjYTowMzoyOToKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAxNjo5ZDo5MDo1Nzo0NjpiNTpmNDowZTphZToxNzpjODowYTo0ZDo5MjplZDoKICAgICAg
ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAwODphNjozMjoyMzoxMTo3MTpmZTpmMjoyYzo0NDpkNzo2YzowNzpmMzowYjoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA3YjowYzo0YjpkZDozYjpi
NDpmNzozNzo3MDo5Zjo1MTpiNjo4ODo0ZTo1ZDoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA2YTowNTo3Zjo4ZDo5Yjo2Njo3YTphYjo4MDoyMDpmZTplZTo2Yjo5NzpjMzoK
ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA0OTo3ZDo3ODozYjpkNTo5OTo5NzowMzo3NTpjZTo4ZjpiYzpjNTpiZTo5YzoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA5YTphNToxMjox
OTo3MDpmOTphNDpiZDo5NjoyNzplZDoyMzowMjphNzpjNzoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA1NzpjOTo3MTpjZjo3Njo5NDphMjoyMTo2MjpmNjpiODoxZDpjYTo4
ODplZToKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAwOTphZDo0NjoyZjpiNzo2MTpiMzoyYzoxNToxMzo4Njo5ZjphNTozNToyNjoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA1YTo2
NzpmNDozNzpjODplNjo4MDowMTo0OTowZTpjNzplZDo2MTpkMzpjZDoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBiYzplNDpmODpiZTozZjpjOTo0ZTpmODo3ZDo5Nzo4OTpj
ZToxMjpiYzpjYToKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBiNTpjNjpkMjplMDpkOTpiMzo2ODozYzoyZTo0YTo5ZDpiNDo1ZjpiODo1MzoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
ICBlZTo1MDozZDpiZjpkZDpkNDphMjo4YTpiNjphMDoyNzphYjo5ODowYzpiMzoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBiMjo1ODo5MDplMjpiYzphMTphZDpmZjpiZDo4
ZTo1NTozMTowZjowMDpiZjoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA2ODplOTozZDphOToxOTo5YTpmMDo2ZDowYjphMjoxNDo2YTpjNjo0YzpjNjoKICAgICAgICAgICAg
ICAgICAgICA0ZTpiZDo2MzoxMjphNTowYjo0ZDo5NzplYjo0MjowOTo3OTo1MzplMjo2NToKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBhYToyNDozNDo3MDpiODpjMTphYjoy
Mzo4MDplNzo5Yzo2YzplZDpkYzo4MjoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBhYTozNzowNDpiODo0MzoyYTozZDoyYTphODpjYzoyMDpmYzoyNzo1ZDo5MDoKICAgICAg
ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAyNjo1ODpmOTpiNzoxNDplMjo5ZTplMjpjMTo3MDo3Mzo5NzplOTo2YjowMjoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA4ZTpkMzo1Mjo1OTo3Yjow
MDplYzo2MTozMDpmMTo1NjozZjo5YzpjMTo3YzoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAwNTpjNTpiMTozNjpjODoxODo4NTpjZjo2MTo0MDoxZjowNzplODphNzowNjoK
ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA4NzpkZjo5YTo3NzowYjphOTo2NDo3MjowMzpmNjo5MzpmYzplMDowMjo1OToKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBjMTo5NjplYzpj
MDowOTo0MjozZTozMDphMjo3ZjoxYjo0ODoyZjpmZTplMDoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAyMTo4Zjo1Mzo4NzoyNTowZDpjYjplYTo0OTpmNTo0YTo5YjpkMDpl
Mzo1ZjoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBlZTo3ODoxODplNTpiYTo3MTozMTphOTowNDo5ODowZjpiMTphZDo2Nzo1MjoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBhMDpm
MjplMzo5YzphYjo2YTpmZTo1ODo4NDo4NDpkZDowNzozZDozMjo5NDoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAwNToxNjo0NToxNTo5Njo1OTphMDo1ODo2YzoxODowZTpl
Mzo3Nzo2NjpjNzoKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBiMzpmNzo5OQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgRXhwb25lbnQ6IDY1NTM3ICgweDEwMDAxKQogICAgICAgIFg1MDl2
MyBleHRlbnNpb25zOgogICAgICAgICAgICBYNTA5djMgQmFzaWMgQ29uc3RyYWludHM6IAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgQ0E6RkFMU0UKICAgICAgICAgICAgTmV0c2Nh
cGUgQ29tbWVudDogCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBPcGVuU1NMIEdlbmVyYXRlZCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZQogICAgICAgICAgICBYNTA5djMgU3ViamVjdCBLZXkgSWRlbnRp
ZmllcjogCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA1OTo1RjpDOToxMzpCQToxQjpDQzpCOTpBODo0MTo0QTo4QTo0OTo3OTo2QTozNjpGNjo3RDozRTpENwogICAgICAgICAgICBY
NTA5djMgQXV0aG9yaXR5IEtleSBJZGVudGlmaWVyOiAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGtleWlkOjIzOjZDOjJEOjNEOjNFOjI5OjVEOjc4OkI4OjZDOjNFOkFBOkUyOkJC
OjJFOjFFOjZDOjg3OkYyOjUzCgogICAgU2lnbmF0dXJlIEFsZ29yaXRobTogc2hhMVdpdGhSU0FFbmNyeXB0aW9uCiAgICAgICAgMTM6ZTc6MDI6NDU6M2U6YTc6YWI6
YmQ6Yjg6ZGE6ZTc6ZWY6NzQ6ODg6YWM6NjI6ZDU6ZGQ6CiAgICAgICAgMTA6NTY6ZDU6NDY6MDc6ZWM6ZmE6NmE6ODA6MGM6Yjk6NjI6YmU6YWE6MDg6YjQ6YmU6MGI6
CiAgICAgICAgZWI6OWE6ZWY6Njg6Yjc6Njk6NmY6NGQ6MjA6OTI6OWQ6MTg6NjM6N2E6MjM6ZjQ6NDg6ODc6CiAgICAgICAgNmE6MTQ6YzM6OTE6OTg6MWI6NGU6MDg6
NTk6M2Y6OTE6ODA6ZTk6ZjQ6Y2Y6ZmQ6ZDU6YmY6CiAgICAgICAgYWY6NGI6ZTQ6YmQ6Nzg6MDk6NzE6YWM6ZDA6ODE6ZTU6NTM6OWY6M2U6YWM6NDQ6M2U6OWY6CiAg
ICAgICAgZjA6YmY6NWE6YzE6NzA6NGU6MDY6MDQ6ZWY6ZGM6ZTg6Nzc6MDU6YTI6N2Q6YzU6ZmE6ODA6CiAgICAgICAgNTg6MGE6YzU6MTA6NmQ6OTA6Y2E6NDk6MjY6
NzE6ODQ6Mzk6Yjc6OWE6M2U6ZTk6NmY6YWU6CiAgICAgICAgYzU6MzU6YjY6NWI6MjQ6OGM6Yzk6ZWY6NDE6YzM6YjE6MTc6YjY6M2I6NGU6Mjg6ODk6M2M6CiAgICAg
ICAgN2U6ODc6YTg6M2E6YTU6NmQ6ZGM6Mzk6MDM6MjA6MjA6MGI6YzU6ODA6YTM6Nzk6MTM6MWU6CiAgICAgICAgZjY6ZWM6YWU6MzY6ZGY6NDA6NzQ6MzQ6ODc6NDY6
OTM6M2I6YTM6ZTA6YTQ6OGM6MmY6NDM6CiAgICAgICAgNGM6YjI6NTQ6ODA6NzE6NzY6Nzg6ZDQ6ZWE6MTI6Mjg6ZDg6ZjI6ZTM6ODA6NTU6MTE6OWI6CiAgICAgICAg
ZjQ6NjU6ZGM6NTM6MGU6YjQ6NGM6ZTA6NGM6MDk6YjQ6ZGM6YTA6ODA6NWM6ZTY6YjU6M2I6CiAgICAgICAgOTU6ZDM6Njk6ZTQ6NTI6M2Q6NWI6NjE6ODY6MDI6ZTU6
ZmQ6MGI6MDA6M2E6ZmE6YjM6NDU6CiAgICAgICAgY2M6Yzk6YTM6NjQ6ZjI6ZGM6MjU6NTk6ODk6NTg6MGQ6OWU6NmU6Mjg6M2E6NTU6NDU6NTA6CiAgICAgICAgNWY6
ODg6Njc6MmE6ZDI6ZTI6NDg6Y2M6OGI6ZGU6OWE6MWI6OTM6YWU6ODc6ZTE6ZjI6OTA6CiAgICAgICAgNTA6NDA6ZDk6MGY6NDQ6MzE6NTM6NDY6YWQ6NjI6NGU6OGQ6
NDg6ODY6MTk6Nzc6ZmM6NTk6CiAgICAgICAgNzU6OTE6Nzk6MzU6NTk6MWQ6ZTM6NGU6MzM6NWI6ZTI6MzE6ZDc6ZWU6NTI6Mjg6NWY6MGE6CiAgICAgICAgNzA6YTc6
YmU6YmI6MWM6MDM6Y2E6MWE6MTg6ZDA6ZjU6YzE6NWI6OWM6NzM6MDQ6YjY6NGE6CiAgICAgICAgZTg6NDY6NTI6NTg6NzY6ZDQ6NmE6ZTY6Njc6MWM6MGU6ZGM6MTM6
ZDA6NjE6NzI6YTA6OTI6CiAgICAgICAgY2I6MDU6OTc6NDc6MWM6YzE6Yzk6Y2Y6NDE6N2Q6MWY6YjE6NGQ6OTM6NmI6NTM6NDE6MDM6CiAgICAgICAgMjE6MmI6OTM6
MTU6NjM6MDg6M2U6MmM6ODY6OWU6N2I6OWY6M2E6MDk6MDU6NmE6N2Q6YmI6CiAgICAgICAgMWM6YTc6Yjc6YWY6OTY6MDg6Y2I6NWI6ZGY6MDc6ZmI6OWM6ZjI6OTU6
MTE6YzA6ODI6ODE6CiAgICAgICAgZjY6MWI6YmY6NWE6MWU6NTg6Y2Q6Mjg6Y2E6N2Q6MDQ6ZWI6YWE6ZTk6Mjk6YzQ6ODI6NTE6CiAgICAgICAgMmM6ODk6NjE6OTU6
YjY6ZWQ6YTU6ODY6N2M6N2M6NDg6MWQ6ZWM6NTQ6OTY6NDc6Nzk6ZWE6CiAgICAgICAgZmM6N2Y6ZjU6MTA6NDM6MGE6OWI6MDA6ZWY6OGE6Nzc6MmU6ZjQ6MzY6NjY6
ZDI6NmE6YTY6CiAgICAgICAgOTU6YjY6OWY6MjM6M2I6MTI6ZTI6ODk6ZDU6YTQ6YzE6MmM6OTE6NGU6Y2I6OTQ6ZTg6M2Y6CiAgICAgICAgMjI6MGU6MjE6Zjk6Yjg6
NGE6ODE6NWM6NGM6NjM6YWU6M2Q6MDU6YjI6NWM6NWM6NTQ6YTc6CiAgICAgICAgNTU6OGY6OTg6MjU6NTU6YzQ6YTY6OTA6YmM6MTk6Mjk6YjE6MTQ6ZDQ6ZTI6YjA6
OTU6ZTQ6CiAgICAgICAgZmY6ODk6NzE6NjE6YmU6OGE6MTY6ODUKLS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUdKekNDQkErZ0F3SUJBZ0lCQVRBTkJna3Fo
a2lHOXcwQkFRVUZBRENCc2pFTE1Ba0dBMVVFQmhNQ1JsSXgKRHpBTkJnTlZCQWdNQmtGc2MyRmpaVEVUTUJFR0ExVUVCd3dLVTNSeVlYTmliM1Z5WnpFWU1CWUdBMVVF
Q2d3UApkM2QzTG1aeVpXVnNZVzR1YjNKbk1SQXdEZ1lEVlFRTERBZG1jbVZsYkdGdU1TMHdLd1lEVlFRRERDUkdjbVZsCmJHRnVJRk5oYlhCc1pTQkRaWEowYVdacFky
RjBaU0JCZFhSb2IzSnBkSGt4SWpBZ0Jna3Foa2lHOXcwQkNRRVcKRTJOdmJuUmhZM1JBWm5KbFpXeGhiaTV2Y21jd0hoY05NVEl3TkRJM01UQXpNVEU0V2hjTk1qSXdO
REkxTVRBegpNVEU0V2pCK01Rc3dDUVlEVlFRR0V3SkdVakVQTUEwR0ExVUVDQXdHUVd4ellXTmxNUmd3RmdZRFZRUUtEQTkzCmQzY3VabkpsWld4aGJpNXZjbWN4RURB
T0JnTlZCQXNNQjJaeVpXVnNZVzR4RGpBTUJnTlZCQU1NQldGc2FXTmwKTVNJd0lBWUpLb1pJaHZjTkFRa0JGaE5qYjI1MFlXTjBRR1p5WldWc1lXNHViM0puTUlJQ0lq
QU5CZ2txaGtpRwo5dzBCQVFFRkFBT0NBZzhBTUlJQ0NnS0NBZ0VBM1cyOStJRDYxOTRiSDZlakxySUM0aGIyVWdvOHY2WkMrTXJjCmsyZE5ZTU5QamNPS0FCdnh4RXRC
YW1uU2FlVS9JWTdGQy9naU42MjJMRXRWLzNvRGNydWEwK3lXdVZhZnl4bVoKeVRLVWI0L0dVZ2FmUlFQZi9laVg5dXJXdXJ0SUs3WGdOR0ZOVWpZUHE0ZFNKUVBQaHdD
SEUvTEtBeWtXblpCWApSclgwRHE0WHlBcE5rdTBJcGpJakVYSCs4aXhFMTJ3SDh3dDdERXZkTzdUM04zQ2ZVYmFJVGwxcUJYK05tMlo2CnE0QWcvdTVybDhOSmZYZzcx
Wm1YQTNYT2o3ekZ2cHlhcFJJWmNQbWt2WlluN1NNQ3A4ZFh5WEhQZHBTaUlXTDIKdUIzS2lPNEpyVVl2dDJHekxCVVRocCtsTlNaYVovUTN5T2FBQVVrT3grMWgwODI4
NVBpK1A4bE8rSDJYaWM0Uwp2TXExeHRMZzJiTm9QQzVLbmJSZnVGUHVVRDIvM2RTaWlyYWdKNnVZRExPeVdKRGl2S0d0LzcyT1ZURVBBTDlvCjZUMnBHWnJ3YlF1aUZH
ckdUTVpPdldNU3BRdE5sK3RDQ1hsVDRtV3FKRFJ3dU1Hckk0RG5uR3p0M0lLcU53UzQKUXlvOUtxak1JUHduWFpBbVdQbTNGT0tlNHNGd2M1ZnBhd0tPMDFKWmV3RHNZ
VER4VmorY3dYd0Z4YkUyeUJpRgp6MkZBSHdmb3B3YUgzNXAzQzZsa2NnUDJrL3pnQWxuQmx1ekFDVUkrTUtKL0cwZ3YvdUFoajFPSEpRM0w2a24xClNwdlE0MS91ZUJq
bHVuRXhxUVNZRDdHdFoxS2c4dU9jcTJyK1dJU0UzUWM5TXBRRkZrVVZsbG1nV0d3WUR1TjMKWnNlejk1a0NBd0VBQWFON01Ia3dDUVlEVlIwVEJBSXdBREFzQmdsZ2hr
Z0JodmhDQVEwRUh4WWRUM0JsYmxOVApUQ0JIWlc1bGNtRjBaV1FnUTJWeWRHbG1hV05oZEdVd0hRWURWUjBPQkJZRUZGbGZ5Uk82Rzh5NXFFRktpa2w1CmFqYjJmVDdY
TUI4R0ExVWRJd1FZTUJhQUZDTnNMVDArS1YxNHVHdytxdUs3TGg1c2gvSlRNQTBHQ1NxR1NJYjMKRFFFQkJRVUFBNElDQVFBVDV3SkZQcWVydmJqYTUrOTBpS3hpMWQw
UVZ0VkdCK3o2YW9BTXVXSytxZ2kwdmd2cgptdTlvdDJsdlRTQ1NuUmhqZWlQMFNJZHFGTU9SbUJ0T0NGay9rWURwOU0vOTFiK3ZTK1M5ZUFseHJOQ0I1Vk9mClBxeEVQ
cC93djFyQmNFNEdCTy9jNkhjRm9uM0Yrb0JZQ3NVUWJaREtTU1p4aERtM21qN3BiNjdGTmJaYkpJekoKNzBIRHNSZTJPMDRvaVR4K2g2ZzZwVzNjT1FNZ0lBdkZnS041
RXg3MjdLNDIzMEIwTklkR2t6dWo0S1NNTDBOTQpzbFNBY1haNDFPb1NLTmp5NDRCVkVadjBaZHhURHJSTTRFd0p0TnlnZ0Z6bXRUdVYwMm5rVWoxYllZWUM1ZjBMCkFE
cjZzMFhNeWFOazh0d2xXWWxZRFo1dUtEcFZSVkJmaUdjcTB1Skl6SXZlbWh1VHJvZmg4cEJRUU5rUFJERlQKUnExaVRvMUloaGwzL0ZsMWtYazFXUjNqVGpOYjRqSFg3
bElvWHdwd3A3NjdIQVBLR2hqUTljRmJuSE1FdGtybwpSbEpZZHRScTVtY2NEdHdUMEdGeW9KTExCWmRISE1ISnowRjlIN0ZOazJ0VFFRTWhLNU1WWXdnK0xJYWVlNTg2
CkNRVnFmYnNjcDdldmxnakxXOThIKzV6eWxSSEFnb0gyRzc5YUhsak5LTXA5Qk91cTZTbkVnbEVzaVdHVnR1MmwKaG54OFNCM3NWSlpIZWVyOGYvVVFRd3FiQU8rS2R5
NzBObWJTYXFhVnRwOGpPeExpaWRXa3dTeVJUc3VVNkQ4aQpEaUg1dUVxQlhFeGpyajBGc2x4Y1ZLZFZqNWdsVmNTbWtMd1pLYkVVMU9Ld2xlVC9pWEZodm9vV2hRPT0K
LS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQo= -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Update:** Use this code to convert cert file to to string (base64), and put output to clipboard, so, past it where you need:

```bat
%__appdir__%certutil -encode /f .\my.crt .\my_crt.txt

(for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('type .\my_crt.txt')do echo/%%i)|clip
```

Just past in your file, `clip`is the same to send output to ***Crtl+C***

**This is an old technique used in some game batch files**.

Comment: Thousand claps for your answers

Comment: @InamulHasan considering edit you question, for be more clear, and change the status, is a good question.